# Teamcity hang on agent side git checkout

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

TeamCity build was working with "On Server" VCS checkout mode. Now I need to have access to .git folder. After switching to checkout mode to "On Agent", build just froze on checkout.

- Repository doesn't contain any big files, checkout is normally up to 10 sec.
- Authentication is via login/password.
- Reconfiguring VCS root didn't help.
- TeamCity version: 9.1.7

Output is the following:

```
[VCS Root: RootName] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-3B190D20.git]: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" remote add origin https://***@bitbucket.org/***.git
[16:50:57][VCS Root: RootName] Cannot stop checkout on agent for RootName. Waiting for the operation to finish.
[16:50:47][VCS Root: RootName] [C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-3B190D20.git]: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8866188247228629665.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master (30m)
[17:20:47][[C:\BuildAgent\system\git\git-3B190D20.git]: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass8866188247228629665.bat fetch --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master] 
[17:20:47][VCS Root: RootName] No output from git during 1800 seconds. Try increasing idle timeout by setting parameter 'teamcity.git.idle.timeout.seconds' either in build or in agent configuration.
[17:20:47]
```

What could be the reason?

***Update***: Got resolved by moving to Agent on Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer for others running into this issue:

1. Stop the Agent
2. Delete work and temp folders
3. Restart Server
4. Start Agent

Explanation:
In my case, 1 configuration of several with the same VCS root and checkout rules was working while the others hung. It turned out something had cached incorrectly and the somewhat nuclear steps above allowed me to build all configurations without issues. Although in my case, the issues were limited to a single agent (the only one that used that VCS root).